# Create A Record as Closed with C#

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can a record be created as closed?

If I create the records and then change the state, that could work, but is it possible to do it in a single step?

I am using ExecuteMultipleRequest to create Cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You have to make two request to create and resolve the case. See the examples below:

```C#
// Create an incident.
var incident = new Incident
{
    CustomerId = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName, _accountId),
    Title = "Sample Incident"
};

_incidentId = _serviceProxy.Create(incident);

// Create the incident's resolution.
var incidentResolution = new IncidentResolution
{
    Subject = "Resolved Sample Incident",
    IncidentId = new EntityReference(Incident.EntityLogicalName, _incidentId)
};

// Close the incident with the resolution.
var closeIncidentRequest = new CloseIncidentRequest
{
    IncidentResolution = incidentResolution,
    Status = new OptionSetValue((int)incident_statuscode.ProblemSolved)
};

_serviceProxy.Execute(closeIncidentRequest);
```

Ref: sdk\SampleCode\CS\BusinessDataModel\Service\CloseAnIncident.cs

Answer (score 1):

You will always need two request, one to create the record and one to change the state.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a plugin close the record on the create, so that way it happens in the same database transaction, but I'm guessing that it wouldn't be worth the over head.